# How to split a user inputted string with a comma

Tags: string, flutter

so my teammate asked me to fix something. But the problem is I don't have any idea what to do.
He asked me to divide the address output with commas -
Ex. Barangay, House Number, Municipality, Street.

But I don't know how to seperate the contents of a string.

The address string contains all the user input data.
This is the code:

```
Widget buildUserAddress() {
return Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 20),
  child: Text(
    address,
    maxLines: 3,
    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 15,
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: use split method on the object "address". FYI: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: You can use: `string.split(",")`

Comment: How do I actually use that in my code kind gentlemen?

Answer (score 0):

below the complete Widget class. As you can see:

1. I split the string and I got a List
2. I put all in column (be free to change how to display)
3. For each element in the list, make a Text widget with label the address element
4. toList() -> list of Text widgets containing each one a part of address
5. ... -> spread operator in order to display each element of the widget list

   ```
   class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return buildUserAddress();
     }

     Widget buildUserAddress() {
       var address = "Barangay, House Number, Municipality, Street";
       List<String> addressList = address.split(',');

       return Container(
         width: 500,
         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 20),
         child: Column(children: [
   ...addressList
       .map(
         (addressElement) => Text(
           addressElement,
           maxLines: 3,
           textAlign: TextAlign.left,
           style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 15,
           ),
         ),
       )
       .toList(),
     ]),
   );
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: I already defined a build, what can I do to fix this?
This is my build 


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    appCount = Provider.of<AppCount>(context);
    params = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    sellerList = params.cartItems;
    debugPrint(sellerList.toString());
    type = params.deliveryType;
    subTotal = getTotalPriceOfTheCart();
    if (isInitialize == false) {
      deliveryNote.clear();
      for (var i = 0; i < sellerList.length; i++) {
        deliveryNote.add(TextEditingController());
      }

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> components = address.split(',');
```

This will split the address and you will get the component list.

And use splitted components to build UI like this.

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: components.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(components[index])
)
```

Comment: Where should I put this line of code? Should I replace the address string with this?

Comment: you put `split` code into `build`, `builder` code into the widget tree